# for-each-loop in c++ for two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, syntax

I know that we can use the following code to print the elements in an array, for example:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (int el : a) {
    cout << el << endl;
}
```

but what if our array has two or more dimensions?
how should modify the for loop in order to print the higher dimension arrays?
for example:

```
int b[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5}};
```

Thank you :)

Comment: in which language do you need the code ?

Comment: I wrote in the title that it's C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
int b[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
for (auto& outer : b)
{
    for (auto& inner : outer)
    {
        std::cout << inner << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please explain why you used "auto" here? 
when I use "int" instead it just shows the memory addresses but with auto, it works!!

Comment: On the `outer` loop the `auto` and the `&` are required so that the array doesn't decay to a pointer. You should get a compilation error if you try to use `int` in the outer loop. In the inner loop you could use `int` and it should be ok. See [Range based for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203382.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**Range-based for loop:**
Below simple example that shows how to print the **2d array** using a *range-based for loop*.

```
unsigned int arr[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }; // 2 rows, 3 columns
for (const auto& row: arr)  // & - copy by reference; const - protect overwrite; 
{
    for (const auto& col : row)
    {
        std::cout << col << " "; // 1 2 3 4 5 6
    }
}
```

Similarly, a *range-based loop* for the **2d vector**:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }; // 2 rows, 3 columns

for (const auto& row : matrix)  // & - copy by reference; const - protect overwrite; 
{
    for (const auto& col : row)
    {
        std::cout << col << " "; // 1 2 3 4 5 6
    }
}
```